# React js createElement throughs SCRIPT1002: Syntax error in IE11

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer-11

Hell All
My website is working fine in Chrome in Firefox but not in IE 11.
It is giving SCRIPT1002: Syntax error in line number 243. Please help me to remove this issue.
 [js link](http://tickets.tandmtickets.com/js/bundle.js).
Please let me know if I missed any info.

BR
Ramukumar M

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show any relevant code

Comment: I have added the script in the post. http://tickets.tandmtickets.com/js/bundle.js

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason, there was a extra comma **","** before the last curly bracket **")"**.
After removing the comma the code worked like expected.
For example

[Error Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AJni.png)

[Corrected Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2NRc.png)

BR
Ramukumar M